# How to shift intersection point of x- and y-axis from 0 to 1 using Python Altair?

Tags: python, altair

I have a dashboard, in which you can select several datasets using a widget. I am using the Altair library in Python to make classical line graphs from these datasets with both x-and y-axis starting at zero. The displayed data are normalized data, meaning all datasets start at the y-value=1 by definition. As the datasets represent different parameters the y-axis changes dynamically from dataset to dataset. The graph is coded roughly like the following:

```
chart = alt.Chart(df_datapoints).mark_line().encode(
        x=alt.X('X-Value',axis=alt.Axis(title='X-Values', tickCount=10)),
        y=alt.Y('Y-Value', axis=alt.Axis(title='Normalized to Baseline')),
        color=alt.Color('Test ID', legend=None)
        )
```

The graph looks then like this:

[image]

Now I would like to have the x-axis starting at y-value=1 to better see which values increase or decrease from the starting point. Is there a possibility to shift the starting point of the x-axis in this simple line graph from  from zero to 1?
I haven't found anything in the Altair Documentation.
Or would it be possible to add a strong line at Y=1 to see the normalized baseline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `axis.offset` property, which controls the offset of the axes in pixels. You'll have to adjust this depending on the bounds of your data if you want the axes to intersect at a particular data point:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'y': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
  x=alt.X('x', axis=alt.Axis(grid=False, offset=-75)),
  y=alt.Y('y', axis=alt.Axis(grid=False, offset=-100))
)
```

[image]

Comment: @jakedvp Thanks a lot for this reply. That works per very well. However, it doesn't solve my problem as the graph is part of a dashboard and different datasets can be chosen by a widget. Therfore the Y-axis dynamiucally changes for each dataset. I will edit my question to make my point more clear.

Comment: There’s no way to offset the axes dynamically in response to the data. What you want to do is not possible with Altair/Vega-Lite. One imperfect way to work around this would be to hide the axes, and construct new “axes” manually using rule and text marks.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the swift reply. I will try to implement at line from x=1/y=1 to x=1/y=9.

Comment: @jakedvp I am trying to add a rule mark at y-value=1 
If I add a code like that:
`rule = base.mark_rule().encode(
    y='min(Visit number)',
    color='black',
    size=alt.value(2)
    )` 
I get the error _argument of type 'int' is not iterable_
What would you suggest to add as y-value for the rule mark?

Comment: You can't set the color encoding to a string, unless `"black'` is the name of a column in your dataset.

Comment: I just left out the color argument and it works wonderful. Now I have a nice black line at y=1 using `y=min(X-axis column)` using the `mark_rule' command. All what I wanted... Thanks a lot! Altair is just great!